# Is there a Java library out there that can aid in drawing cellular automata graphics?

Tags: java, graphics

I feel like this kind of task must be done pretty often but I am unable to find any widely known libraries or packages that can support this functionality. For example, this could be useful for Conway's Game of Life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like MASON is the answer:

http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/

for those who are curious

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Processing? There are numerous cellular automata implementations, including this fairly detailed example:

http://processing.org/learning/topics/wolfram.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered game engines? These are not actually aimed for drawing cellular automata, but can help a lot with drawing of 2d-graphics in general:

[Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/)
[Golden T Game Engine (GTGE)](http://goldenstudios.or.id/products/GTGE/)
[LightWeight Java Game Library (LWJGL)](http://lwjgl.org/)